# Best way to update and notify by service a JSON get request

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I thinked and crushed in all directions since. But, I don't have an idea on the best way to architecture my Android application.

**Concept**

My application get JSON array list by OkHttp3. After response, the application put this list on a list view by the Adapter. I would like every new items on the list to notify my user. I would like to write a service in background to notify my user even when the application is gone.

[image: architecture my service]

I need a service to maintain the flux of notifications (as facebook, twitter).

It was after the problem. So, how to do that correctly ?

**My Item Class**

```
public class ItemDevis implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int id;
private String name;
private String description;
private String picture;
private int price;
private int number;
private int millesime;
private int color;
private int status;

public ItemDevis(int id, String name, String description,
    int number, int millesime, int color, int status, int price) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.millesime = millesime;
    this.color = color;
    this.description = description;
    this.status = status;
    this.number = number;
    this.price = price;
}
}
```

**My service**

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {

    private NotificationManager mNM;
    private int NOTIFICATION = R.string.notification;
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    static final int timer = 5000;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        if (!isRunning) {
            mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mNM.cancel(NOTIFICATION);
        isRunning = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (!isRunning) {
            isRunning = true;
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("DATA", "HTTP Request!");
                    // Check, if new item -> update view (if application is ready) + notify.
                    handler.postDelayed(this, timer);
                }
            }, timer);
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

**How do you like that solution ?**

[image]

**My Questions**

- Should I use a SQLite ?
- Should I use a ContentProvider ?
- SQLite is it more efficient in that situation ?
- Should I review my schema ?

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to fulfill your requirement.

1. Make a service which after a time interval repeat. when it get a new data store it on db, as well show notifications (note: yes you have to store data somewhere).
2. Implement GCM on your server. whenever something new is added send push notification to your device on receiving end first store data in db then check if app is open then simply update the view else generate a notification.

Note : There is no need to use content provider

Comment: How did you get there without content provider and the point n°1 mentioned ? How did you send the data between the service and the applications without content provider ? Can you explain more details about the solution n°1 ? Pros and Cons between the differents solutions.

Comment: simply store data on sqlite from service and in activity fetch data from sqlite. so you need not content provider

Comment: But, I read this method has more latency. Because fetch data from sqlite is more slower that to get the content provider, right ? Thank you for your help man.

Comment: When no. of data is quite huge.. its better to store somewhere than using content provider. for small information you can use